# Horizontal scroll view and image views?

Tags: android

I want to add a number of image views to a `HorizontalScrollView` dynamically.
I have my scroll view:

```
myScroller = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
```

Then:

```
myScroller.addView(myImageView1);
```

This works, but I want to add more than one image view to the scroller, then it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try it to adding more images as like: myScroller.addView(anotherImageView);

Comment: Please print the error catlog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HorizontalScrollView can only have 1 child, so you need to put all the images inside a horizontal linearLayout and add it to the HorizontalScrollView.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Take a horizontal scrollview, and take a horizontal linear layout inside it, then if u know how many number of images are there? take it in for loop, add them imageview one by one into linearlayout...!!

Answer (score 1):

If you add ImageViews you could also use Gallery which will also scroll horizontally and you can use an adapter to set the content.

If you want to stick to the ScrollView you can only have one child, so you have to add a container like a LinearLayout where you're adding your ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView it allow only one child view,
`A ScrollView should place 
    one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `HorizontalScrollView` to do that is much harder than using the `ViewPager` class that comes in the [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

For more info, read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) blog post.